# Returning a function from a separate python file in django

Tags: python, django

I have a project that just creates a plot.
The code to generates this plot is stored in `theplot.py` from a function called `theplotfunction`.

What i am trying to do is to show this plot to the user by pressing a `HTML` button in my `index.html` but it is not loading.
I have my `theplot.py` to create the plot:

THEPLOT.PY:

```
def theplotfunction(request):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import io
    from django.shortcuts import render

    plt.plot(range(10))
    fig = plt.gcf()
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(buf,format='png')
    buf.seek(0)
    string = base64.b64encode(buf.read())
    uri = urllib.parse.quote(string)
    return render(request, 'plot.html',{'data':uri})
```

I then link my url to go to a function in `views.py`.

URLS.PY:

`path('plot', views.plot, name='plot'),`

Then the `views.py` plot function will go to the `theplot.py` to run the code to generate the plot.

VIEWS.PY:

```
`from .theplot import theplotfunction`

def plot(request):

return (theplotfunction)
```

My `index.html` shows the connection to views function to be run

INDEX.HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="plot" onclick="window.open('plot')">
```

finally the `plot.html` is shown to the user and the graph is seen
PLOT.HTML:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ data }}" alt="" height="250" ,width="250">
```

my problem is the I click the button to generate the plot i get a `function' object has no attribute 'get'` error. The code worked when i generated the graph in `views.py` so i know the graphing code is good. however when i changed it so that the graphing function was generated from `theplot.py` it does not seem to work. I would feel the issue is with returning the `theplottingfunction` in `views.py`. i have played around with it but cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: I think you meant `return theplotfunction(request)`?

Comment: Thank you that fixed it